# getting current year in a dropdown of years

Tags: javascript, html

This is my dropdown in html

```
<select name="select" class="form-control" id="dropdownYear" style="width: 120px;" onchange="getProjectReportFunc()">
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017" selected="selected">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
```

I have hard coded the year values, i want to populate this dropdown
 with current year selected and 3 years before and after that.Eg for
 current year=2017 i want the list to be 2013-2020 with 2017
 automatically selected. How do i do this in js?

Comment: what did you try? you probably need to use [`Date.prototype.getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) with [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can search On W3School Site
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Comment: @Abhilasha, what about my solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like this :

```js
$('#dropdownYear').each(function() {

  var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
  var current = year;
  year -= 3;
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if ((year+i) == current)
      $(this).append('<option selected value="' + (year + i) + '">' + (year + i) + '</option>');
    else
      $(this).append('<option value="' + (year + i) + '">' + (year + i) + '</option>');
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" class="form-control" id="dropdownYear" style="width: 120px;" onchange="getProjectReportFunc()">
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

To achieve this, using [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is required, be it directly or with some external library.  With the native method `getFullYear`:

> `Date.prototype.getFullYear()`
>
> Returns the year (4 digits for 4-digit years) of the specified date according to local time.

We can set the current year and then loop through desired values.  You specified 2013 - 2020, so we'll use the current year minus 4 up to the current year plus 3.

```
for (var i = year - 4; i <= year + 3; i++)
```

In the body of the loop, create [Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) and add them to the [Select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select). To display the values, the `innerHTML` needs to be set, and if you want to use the value somewhere else in your javascript, the `value` also needs to be set:

```
option.value = option.innerHTML = i;
```

If the index equals the current year, set the `selected` attribute.

```
if (i === year) option.selected = true;
```

Then, all you need to do is append each `option` element to the `select` element.  After the `select` has been created, insert it into your HTML (here I am appending to the body).

```js
var select = document.createElement('select');
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
for (var i = year - 4; i <= year + 3; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = option.innerHTML = i;
  if (i === year) option.selected = true;
  select.appendChild(option);
}
document.body.appendChild(select);
```

Comment: Nice and clean. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Dan-LeviTømta, or using `ES6` stuff for more less solution like in my answer :)

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Yeah it's less lines and pretty cute, but I think trying to avoid confusion for someone who is starting with javascript is a better idea.

Comment: @SvenWritesCode, yes, that's true. +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var i, currentYear, startYear, endYear, newOption, dropdownYear;
dropdownYear = document.getElementById("dropdownYear");
currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
startYear = currentYear - 4;
endYear = currentYear + 3;

for (i=startYear;i<=endYear;i++) {
  newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.value = i;
  newOption.label = i;
 if (i == currentYear) {
  newOption.selected = true;
 }
  dropdownYear.appendChild(newOption);
}
```

```html
<select name="select" class="form-control" id="dropdownYear"
 style="width: 120px;" onchange="getProjectReportFunc()">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple logic,

- First get current year,
- Then run loop starting from currentyear -2 to currenct year + 3
- Make current year `selected`

See code below:

```js
console.clear();
var curYear = new Date().getFullYear();

for(i = curYear-2 ; i <= curYear+3 ; i++) {
  var selected = (curYear === i) ? 'selected="selected"': '';
  console.log('<option '+selected+' value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ES6` array features.

```js
let currentYear=new Date().getFullYear();
let array=Array.from(Array(7), (_, i) => currentYear-3+i);
array.forEach(function(item){
   let option=$('<option></option>').html(item).attr('selected', item == currentYear);
   $('select').append(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" class="form-control" id="dropdownYear">

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example, without using JQuery -

```
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var yearSelect = document.getElementById('dropdownYear');
for(var i = -2; i < 3; i++) {
    var isSelected = currentYear === currentYear - i
    yearSelect.options[yearSelect.options.length] = new Option(currentYear - i, currentYear - i, isSelected, isSelected);
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<select name="select" class="form-control" id="dropdownYear" style="width: 120px;" onchange="getProjectReportFunc()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select 
         name="select"
         class="form-control"
         id="dropdownYear"
         style="width: 120px;"
         onchange="getProjectReportFunc()">
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
let select = document.getElementById('dropdownYear');
let currYear = new Date().getFullYear();
let futureYear = currYear+3;
let pastYear = currYear-3;
for(let year = pastYear; year <= futureYear; year++){
  let option = document.createElement('option');
  option.setAttribute('value', year);
  if(year === currYear){
    option.setAttribute('selected', true);
  }
  option.innerHTML = year;
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I appreciated a lot of these answers, I felt like these could and should be done using the modern tools `.map` and `Array` constructor, so I created the below:

```
const CreateYearDropdown = () => {
  const nYearsPrior = 20;
  const nYearsPost = 20;
  const yearRange = Array(nYearsPrior+nYearsPost).fill(0);
  const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  const years = yearRange.map(
    (item, index) => (item[index] = currentYear - nYearsPrior + index)
  );

  return (
    <select defaultValue={currentYear}>
      {years.map((year, index) => (
        <option key={index} value={year}>
          {String(year)}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  )
}
```

Without the above explanation/breakdown, it can be written like so:

```
const CreateYearDropdown = () => {
  const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  const yearRange = Array(40).fill(0);
  const years = yearRange.map(
    (item, index) => (item[index] = currentYear - 20 + index)
  );

  return (
    <select defaultValue={currentYear}>
      {years.map((year, index) => (
        <option key={index} value={year}>
          {year}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};
```

Alternatively you can have it running in a single direction (before or after):

```
const CreateYearDropdown = () => {
  const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  const yearRange = Array(20).fill(0);
  const years = yearRange.map(
    (item, index) => (item[index] = currentYear /* - or + */ + index)
  );

  return (
    <select defaultValue={currentYear}>
      {years.map((year, index) => (
        <option key={index} value={year}>
          {year}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};
```